# Get Facebook profile name using profile id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Am using php sdk to get facebook information. I have an array of facebook ids. 
facebook ids 100003186894762, 100002039757708, 100001527538655, 100005502043347

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook ->setAccessToken($access_token);
$user_profile = $facebook->api(/100003186894762);
```

Here am getting one user information. Is there any way to get an array of information in a single request.

like this way

$user_profile = `$facebook>api(/100003186894762/100002039757708/100001527538655/100005502043347);`

I tried with looping each request but its taking too much time 
$resultfbid is an array of facebook ids

```
foreach($resultfbid as $key=>$fbid) {
           $user_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$fbid);
           $posts[] = array('name'=> $user_profile['first_name'], 'id'=> $user_profile['id'],'status'=>$resultstatus[$key] );
       }
```

Please help me to find one solution for this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the API for multiple IDs by using a GET parameter `id` and list the ids comma-separated:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Ffields%3Dname%26ids%3D100003186894762%2C100002039757708%2C100001527538655%2C100005502043347

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/100003186894762/picture' );
```

Comment: yes i can get picture..i need to get the profile name..is there any way